# Android: OnClick Listener in an adapter or outside of it?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, adapter

Performance wise, is it the same to place an onclick listener in a getView() call of an adapter or place the onclick listener outside on a listview that contains the adapter?

My underlying thought is to reduce code if I use the same adapter in two different places. But I need to make sure the performance wouldn't be affected!

Comment: i don't think the performance will be affected if you used the same on-click listener for different places .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference would be so negligible, I wouldn't even worry about it.  Instead opting for whatever seems to be fit for your design approach.  If you want to reduce code duplication, putting it in the `getView()` works just fine.